# jquery migrate error with js files

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a custom wordpress theme with some JS files but I get following error on home page :

```
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selector' of undefined
    at a.fn.init (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
    at n (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (business.js?ver=1.0.0:1)
    at t (shared.js?ver=1.0.0:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (business.js?ver=1.0.0:1)
    at t (shared.js?ver=1.0.0:3)
    at window.webpackJsonp (shared.js?ver=1.0.0:3)
    at business.js?ver=1.0.0:1
```

You can see my demo at : http://pcomplex.zafredemo.ir/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: link not working

Comment: try to turn on and off VPN to see the site.

Comment: not sure it's an issue with Jqery migrate, if you read the errors it comes from **business.js** ... is your site not working fine ? cause it's seems ok for me. Sometimes you may get some errors but they aren't critical.

Comment: yes, it works fine but I have issue with scrolling on mobile, the page jumps on home page if you scroll down or up. I though it might be related to this error. would you mind checking on mobile and let me know what the solution is?

Answer (score 0):

I limited Js files to screen larger than 768px to fix this.